# Calling a public method inside a class

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013

below is the coding I'm using to call `doingThing()` from `myMethod()` in the Testing class. But it has error.

```
namespace Printing_io
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class Testing
    {
        public void myMethod()
        {
           doingThing();  // error here
        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    public void doingThing()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

How do i call a function `doingThing()` in `myMethod()`?

Comment: the testing class has no reference to the doingThing function. It will need an instance of the Form1 class to be able to execute the function, or the doingThing function needs to become a static function

Comment: U mean add something like this "Form1 form = new Form1(); form.doingThing();"

Comment: yes that would work, although I don't think thats what you want? Try to explain what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: That's what i want bro, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

Either declare your  doingThing() function as static:

```
public static void doingThing()
```

or

```
    public void myMethod()
    {
       Form1 f=new Form1()
       f.doingThing();  // error here
    }
```

Non static methods needs to be instantiated. while static methods can be called directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that without passing in an instance of `Form1`. You can either do this by passing the instance of the form to the method, or by saving the instance of the form upon initializing the `Testing` class, passing it to the constructor:

```
namespace Printing_io
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class Testing
        {
            public void myMethod(Form1 form)
            {
               form.doingThing();  // error here
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        public void doingThing()
        {
        }
    }
}
```